# How to Create a Provisioning Profile for Mac App Distribution

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile

After completing all MAC development, only the deployment stage remains.

I'm a complete beginner developer on MAC.

But when I was deploying, the gatekeeper blocked me, and when I deployed I knew I had to build with a new provisioning file.

So I tried to make it on the Apple Developer site but all failed )-:

Please see below for the steps I followed

1. Generate a certificate on the MAC PC (.CSR)
2. Create a Developer ID Application certificate in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles screen (using the .CSR created in step 1)
   [image]
3. After that, I went to Profile and selected the option to deploy using Developer ID and proceeded, but only the message that there is no certificate is displayed as shown below.
   [image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failure to create a provisioning profile using Developer ID when there is an actual certificate is an Apple problem, and the problem has been resolved in Apple Korea.

It took Apple about 3 weeks to solve the problem, and when I got a response and checked, it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Mac App Distribution` certificate in the certificates section. You can then select this `Mac App Distribution` when creating a provisioning profile if it is a `Mac App Store` distribution type.

The certificate needed and process is a bit different if you select `macOS App Development` type for your provisioning profile.